# Java regex patter.compile() cannot be resolved symbol

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I am trying to write a regex in Java with Intellij IDE but **.compile()** is getting

> cannot resolve symbol 'compile'

```
private boolean isUrlFormatValid(String url) {
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern.compile("blabla");
        //some other stuff
    }
```

And I have imported these at the beginning of the class:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

.compile is not resolved. Do I need to add something else or you think something is wrong with intellij idea ?

Note: I have also tried by defining with full path like:

```
Pattern p = new java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("blabla");
```

But did not work as well.

Comment: Don't need to use `new`. `compile` is a static member of `Pattern` Just make it `java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("blabla");` or import `Pattern` class

Comment: Try Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("blabla");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pattern.compile("blabla");` This is a static method on the `Pattern` class (notice the capital P in `Pattern`. A static method does not need an instance to run. So simply remove the `new` keyword.